# Make another page refresh with javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am writing a debug console to use in PHP, to which you can output values from any place in the project. It sits in another page and everything works just as I want except I have to refresh it manually every time there's new output. What I want to do is somehow call reload of the console page on new information, or better yet at the end of each reload. How would one do such a thing, no prewritten code requested, but if someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be thankful.

Currently I have the console on another page in an iframe with a button on top reloading the contents, if I could send a signal to it somehow to do it, that would be awesome.

Comment: Learn about web sockets

Comment: If you vote it down, comment why please...

Comment: you can refresh another frame with JS

Comment: @rlatief, even when it is on another tab?
The whole point of this console is to be on another page so I can debug stuff, when multiple redirects, etc happen

Comment: you mentioned "another page in an iframe", not another tab ;) But I believe it can also be done with JS although less reliable probably (if many people with different browsers will be using it). Put `refresh another tab js` to google and you'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest method, as mentioned in the comments would be to use an iframe, if possible. Another method would be to have your script make an ajax post to a script on your server, then have the output page make an ajax request at a set interval to check for changes.